# How to process data from the facebook graph api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Koala gem to access the facebook graph api.

When I make a call I get back:

```
<%= @fb.inspect %>
```

Output:

```
[{"name"=>"Bob Jones", "id"=>"13223123112323"}]
```

How do I access name?

```
@fb.id works for id but
@fb.name does not work?
```

Error:

```
undefined method `name' for [{.....
```

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array of [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) objects.

```
@fb.first["name"]
```

You must get the first (in this case only) object for the array, and then get the value for the "name" key out from it.